# Need to access sqlite database using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, database, sqlite

How can I access sqlite database using Javascript? Which is the easiest install/use development tool for Javascript?

Actually server is light-weight(thttpd) and is running on an arm-processor. I just need access to sqlite db and display some details on a webpage on clicking hypertext or button. Hope you know the installation of for said packages is not straightforward on arm-platform.

Comment: What server side JavaScript environment? node? Classic ASP? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

I would choose [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) as a platform, and use the [sqlite3](http://search.npmjs.org/#/sqlite3) npm package to access the database.